# PCL : missing property

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-5.0, portable-class-library, resourcemanager

While migrating some code to a PCL targeting .Net4.5 / Silverlight5, the [`IgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.ignorecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on [`ResourceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Resources.ResourceManager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class disappears.

This property exists both in [.Net4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.ignorecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Silverlight5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.ignorecase%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), so the "intersection" of both APIs should have left it available. (this property exists since [.Net2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.ignorecase%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and doesn't seems deprecated)

I use `IgnoreCase` as a fallback to retrieve resx values. I found some specific info's on msdn about [`ResourceManager with PCL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh871422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but nothing about this "`IgnoreCase` issue".

- Why is there such a strange API behavior ?
- Is there a workaround to retrieve `ResourceManager` values with case-insensitive keys ?

Last but not least, I decompiled Profile24 & Profile47\mscorlib.dll with Reflector, it seems `ResourceManager` is just not implemented.. (it's `GetString` methods just returns null), and of course this `IgnoreCase` is absent. What am I missing ?

Comment: The PCL profiles produce a minimum viable common subset of the .NET platform based on the underlying capabilities of the system. Why particular functionality is missing from any particular profile is based on some limitation of the supported platforms. Moved this to a comment because it doesn't really answer the question of 'why'.

Comment: Yes, I know that, the fact is this property is present both on .Net 4.5 and in Silverlight 5... And PCL should produce in this case the "intersection" of both APIs. The "minimum common subset" is well explained here as an intersection : http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/03/27/portable-class-libraries-or-source-code-sharing/ ResourceManager is present in both API's, and the IgnoreCase property too. So my question are : what happens ? why does this happens ? and is there a workaround ?

Comment: Looks like it might be related to the comment about performance of case insensitive searches.  They recommend not doing it, so they took away the ability?

Answer (score 1):

I don't specifically know why this property wasn't included, but I suspect it was because we didn't recommend using it or wanted the option to remove support for it in future platforms.

You can see a general list of why APIs might not be portable in my [blog post on PCLs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for reactivity :) Usually on .Net such properties are marked [Obsolete] before being removed, could it be just an omission ? And do you know if there's a workaround ?